# Writing a __init__ function to be used in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to write an `__init__` function for one of my models so that I can create an object by doing:

```
p = User('name','email')
```

When I write the model, I have:

```
def __init__(self, name, email, house_id, password):
    models.Model.__init__(self)
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
```

This works and I can save the object to the database, but when I do `User.objects.all()`, it doesn't pull anything up unless I take out my `__init__` function. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  That capability is part of a Django model without you writing any code at all.

Comment: When I try it without the init, they all go into the wrong field for some reason, unless I specify User(name='aoeu'), which takes up a lot of extra space.

Comment: What's wrong with explicit field=value assignments?  In the long run, you'll probably be happier.  After all, you write only a very few of these kinds of lines of code.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Relying on Django's built-in functionality and passing named parameters would be the simplest way to go.

```
p = User(name="Fred", email="fred@example.com")
```

But if you're set on saving some keystrokes, I'd suggest adding a static convenience method to the class instead of messing with the initializer.

```
# In User class declaration
@classmethod
def create(cls, name, email):
  return cls(name=name, email=email)

# Use it
p = User.create("Fred", "fred@example.com")
```

Comment: Yeah, a factory method is the way to go here.  You could also consider putting it on the Manager.  Messing with the constructor signature will definitely break things.

Comment: @classmethod on create is also nicer

Answer (score 51):

Django expects the signature of a model's constructor to be `(self, *args, **kwargs)`, or some reasonable facsimile. Your changing the signature to something completely incompatible has broken it.

Comment: As of Django 2.1, Ignacio's answer is the correct one and should be accepted.  Straight from the 2.1 docs, they say `You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the __init__ method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being saved.` from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/

Comment: The link of the above comment will also have suggestions on how to do differently what you want to do. Overriding `__init__` can lead to all kinds of strange bugs, as I have learned from experience this afternoon.

Answer (score 26):

The correct answer is to avoid overriding `__init__` and write a classmethod as described in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

But this could be done like you're trying, you just need to add in `*args, **kwargs` to be accepted by your `__init__`, and pass them on to the super method call.

```
def __init__(self, name, email, house_id, password, *args, **kwargs):
        super(models.Model, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
```

Comment: super(models.Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: `super(<YourModelName>, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't create models with args parameters.  If you make a model like so:

```
 User('name','email')
```

It becomes very unreadable very quickly as most models require more than that for initialization. You could very easily end up with:

```
User('Bert', 'Reynolds', 'me@bertreynolds.com','0123456789','5432106789',....)
```

Another problem here is that you don't know whether 'Bert' is the first or the last name.  The last two numbers could easily be a phone number and a system id.  But without it being explicit you will more easily mix them up, or mix up the order if you are using identifiers.  What's more is that doing it order-based will put yet another constraint on other developers who use this method and won't remember the arbitrary order of parameters.

You should prefer something like this instead:

```
User(
    first_name='Bert',
    last_name='Reynolds',
    email='me@bertreynolds.com',
    phone='0123456789',
    system_id='5432106789',
)
```

If this is for tests or something like that, you can use a factory to quickly create models.  The factory boy link may be useful: http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/