# Inheritance and factory functions in Python and Django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I'm creating a Django app that uses some inheritance in it's model, mainly because I need to assign everything a UUID and a reference so I know what class it was.  Here's a simplified version of the base class:

```
class BaseElement(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=64, editable=False, blank=True, default=lambda:unicode(uuid4()))
    objmodule = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)
    objclass = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)

class ChildElement(BaseElement):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'd like to make sure that objmodule, objclass, and uuid are set automatically.  I've learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model) that it's a bad idea to do that by writing my own constructor, and that I'm better off writing a factory function.  So now my BaseElement and ChildElement looks like this:

```
class BaseElement(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=64, editable=False, blank=True, default=lambda:unicode(uuid4()))
    objmodule = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)
    objclass = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)

    def set_defaults(self):
        self.objmodule = unicode(self.__class__.__module__)
        self.objclass = unicode(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.uuid = unicode(uuid4())

class ChildElement(BaseElement):
    somefield = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @staticmethod
    def create(*args, **kwargs):
        ce = ChildElement(*args, **kwargs)
        ce.set_defaults()
        return ce
```

This works.  I can call `ChildElement.create(somefield="foo")` and I will get an appropriate object with `uuid`, `objmodule`, and `objclass` fields set correct.  However, as I go through and create more classes like `ChildElement2` and `ChildElement3`, I'm finding that I'm inserting the exact same static factory function.  This grates on me because code duplication is bad.

With normal methods I'd just insert the `create` factory function in `BaseElement`, however, I can't do that here because I don't have a handle to self (because it hasn't been created yet) to get information about the class of the object that invoked the method.

Is there a way that I can migrate this factory into the `BaseElement` class so I don't have to duplicate this code everywhere and still have it so it automatically sets the values of `uuid`, `objmodule`, and `objclass`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you make `create()` a `@classmethod` instead of `@staticmethod`, you'll have access to the class object, which you can use instead of referring to it by name:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    obj = cls(*args, **kwargs)
    obj.set_defaults()
    return obj
```

This is now generic and can go on the base class instead of each child class.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for reminding me about `@classmethod`.  It's not something I use very often.

Comment: In Python there is rarely a good use case for `@staticmethod` - that's the one that you probably should use less often, if ever. Often if something isn't a `@classmethod` it's more appropriate as a simple top-level function in a module.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have been better off overriding save in your BaseElement instead. Then on save you could set those fields. It'd be something like:

```
class MyBase(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=64, editable=False, blank=True,
        default=lambda:unicode(uuid4()))
    objmodule = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)
    objclass = models.CharField(max_length=255, editable=False, blank=False)

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.objmodule = unicode(self.__class__.__module__)
            self.objclass = unicode(self.__class__.__name__)
            self.uuid = unicode(uuid4())
        super(self.__class__.__base__, self).save()

class InheritedFromBase(MyBase):
    new_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I tested with that and it seemed to do what you're looking for. I was able to create an "InheritedFromBase" object that had the fields you needed, without a lot of code duplication.

Comment: +1: Simply override `save` is almost always the right thing to do.

Comment: That's close, and may prove to be acceptable, but is not quite what I need. Right now I create some objects on the server then serialize them to a client for use in an AJAXy app.  The client can modify attributes and then save the objects.  With your setup they wouldn't get `uuid`, `objmodule`, and `objclass` assigned until they are saved.  As I use `uuid` on the client, I would probably need to add some additional logic to the server, or have the client assign it.  So close, but I'd like to find a way without invoking `save` first.  I can deal if this is the right way, however.