# Adding to the "constructor" of a django model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to do an extra initalization whenever instances of a specific django model are created.  I know that [overriding __init__ can lead to trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model). What other alternatives should I consider?

**Update. Additional details:** The intent is to initialize a state-machine that the instances of that model represent. This state-machine is provided by an imported library, and it's inner state is persisted by my django-model. The idea is that whenever the model is loaded, the state machine would be automatically initialized with the model's data.

Comment: You've misinterpreted that question. It's not that overriding `__init__` doesn't work, the OP just did it all wrong. You're free to override `__init__`, but the efficacy of that is entirely dependent on what exactly you're trying to do. So why don't you tell us that, so we can actually help you.

Comment: Thanks, I've reread the other thread. You mean, if I keep the signature ```(self, *args, **kwargs)```, overriding \_\_init\_\_ won't get on django's way?

Comment: I've added some more info to the question to clarify the intent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a \_\_init\_\_ function to be used in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model)

Answer (score 25):

Overriding `__init__` might work, but it's bad idea and it's not the Django way.

The proper way of doing it in Django is using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

The ones that are of interest to you in this case are `pre_init` and `post_init`.

> [`django.db.models.signals.pre_init`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-init)
>
> Whenever you instantiate a Django
>   model, this signal is sent at the beginning of the model’s `__init__()`
>   method.
>
> [`django.db.models.signals.post_init`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-init)
>
> Like `pre_init`, but this one is sent
>   when the `__init__()`: method finishes

So your code should be something like

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_init

class MyModel(models.Model):
  # normal model definition...

def extraInitForMyModel(**kwargs):
   instance = kwargs.get('instance')
   do_whatever_you_need_with(instance)

post_init.connect(extraInitForMyModel, MyModel)
```

You can as well connect signals to Django's predefined models.

Comment: In what way is it a bad idea to override `__init__`? It presents no more issues in django than in any other situation.

Comment: vartec I know it's been a while, but I just bumped into your reply and I'm curious. Why do you say that signals is the Django way? Why not one of the two ways described in the Django documentation to solve this precise situation?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model
Thanks

Comment: The updated link from the previous comment is this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/instances/

Comment: Now this one is accesible: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/

Comment: I would not recommend using signals for this purpose. You can get the same result by overriding the save() method, but signals are usually harder to maintain and debug. See also this article on when to use signals and when not: https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

Comment: Current version as of now:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that there often is a better approach than overriding the `__init__` for what you want to do, it is possible and there might be cases where it could be useful.

Here is an example on how to correctly override the `__init__` method of a model without interfering with Django's internal logic:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # add your own logic
```

Answer (score 5):

The two suggested methods in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects) rely on the instance being created in an arbitrary way:

1. Add a classmethod on the model class:

   ```
   from django.db import models

   class Book(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

       @classmethod
       def create(cls, title):
           book = cls(title=title)
           # do something with the book
           return book

   book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
   ```
2. Add a method on a custom manager:

   ```
   class BookManager(models.Manager):
       def create_book(self, title):
           book = self.create(title=title)
           # do something with the book
           return book

   class Book(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

       objects = BookManager()

   book = Book.objects.create_book("Pride and Prejudice")
   ```

If that is your case, I would go that way. If not, I would stick to @vartec's answer.

Comment: Is there a rule of the thumb to know which method is more appropriate than the other one depending on the context?