# Sending email after POST request with Django and Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am using Tastypie to create an API for a Django project. What I'd like to do is to send an email after a POST request to a vouchers resource (creating a new voucher). Does anybody know what's the best solution to this problem?

I am not sure how can I intercept the request and process it. A solution that comes to mind is to override the model's constructor and send the email when the instance is created! I don't know whether this is a good idea or not.

The answer to this question seems a possible solution: [Adding to the "constructor" of a django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415616/adding-to-the-constructor-of-a-django-model)

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use post_save in Django Signals. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

You can check the **created** parameter to know if you need to send an email.