# Django admin form overriding the default value

Tags: python, django

I am setting the default value in django model constructor like this

```
class Student(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  location = models.TextField()
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.location="sample"
        super(Student, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now i am excluding the location field in the admin form.
But if do this in StudentAdmin

```
   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        raise Exception(obj.location)
```

Then it is commig as empty

Comment: Post the code for `StudentAdmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django has its own way to set the default value.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    location = models.TextField(default="sample")
```

EDIT1:

since django will init the instance again, your value just will be overwrite.
   change the order may help.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    super(Student, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.location="sample"
```

#### HOWEVER.

> Relying on Django's built-in functionality and passing named
>   parameters would be the simplest way to go.
>   [Writing a __init__ function to be used in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model)

Comment: but what is the problem with my method

Comment: you can change the order to make your location assign works. However, it may still cause another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default) model field argument to set a default value. If you exclude the field from being edited in any form, the default value will be used.

You would only need to override the save method if you wanted to change the default, or set one if you hadn't already done so in the model or form.