# Creating a model with null attribute. Bug in Django 1.3.6?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I start with this:

```
from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
     id = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
     name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False)
```

Now if I create a new object with a name and without an id, the id will be replaced with an empty string and the object creation will be successful.

```
example = Example.objects.create(name="test")
```

I would like it to return an error instead since I specified `null=False` and `blank=False`. Is there a "native" way to do it?
I'm using Django 1.3.6.

Comment: if you look at the doc ; dont use null for Charfield https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model

Comment: Well, I'm prohibiting `null` but Django decides that when I give it `None` it should be converted to an empty string...

Comment: @mshsayem, it seems that user was trying to implement something different.

Comment: @youcha : so try blank=False , the validation should then failed.

Comment: Despite my answer, `blank=False` by default. Could you show us the correct code? Please copy it and paste it exactly; for example, it's `CharField`, not `Charfield`.

Comment: This discussion seems to have the answer: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/django-users/137yvzse5s/django-not-enforcing-blank-false-on-a-model

Comment: @AntonisChristofides , that says that `blank=False` makes the input field required. It is not the case. I just created an object with no `id` while the model description contained `blank=False` for the `id` field.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.3.6, that might also be a Django bug. I'm just going to override the save method to raise an exception there.

Comment: One a side note - use a better column name than ID. You are overriding the default `id` field

Comment: @Youcha Where does the link I provided say what you say it says? The whole discussion is exactly about the problem you are having.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides the discussion is about the problem I am having but I can't see the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, of course, but is fully explained in the documentation. From the [field options docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#field-options):

> If a field has blank=True, form validation will allow entry of an empty value. If a field has blank=False, the field will be required.

The key is the reference to *validation*. The docs also, naturally, have a whole selection on [data validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/validators/). Again, from that page:

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

So, as the model validation page explains, to apply the validation for blank=False you should run the model's `full_clean()` method.

(In any case, there's no point in complaining about a possible bug in a version that's two releases old: if you think there is a bug, you should upgrade to the latest version and see if it has been fixed. Anyway, it's not a bug.)

Comment: Do you mean the way to go is to override the save method to run `full_clean` before saving?