# Django model id turns into a tuple

Tags: django, django-models

I have a super class for my models as below:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """ BaseClass vase aksare model ha """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__(args, kwargs)
        print('******> base model __init__')

    status = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_creator_related")
    create_date = models.DateTimeField()
    update_date = models.DateTimeField()
    update_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updater_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def validate(self):
        print('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^base validation')
```

and I have a profile model as below:

```
class Profile(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).__init__(args, kwargs)

    """ User profile """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')

    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    firstname_en = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    lastname_en = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    gender = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    birth_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    edu_bg = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name="profile__edu_bg", null=True)
    region = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name="profile__region", null=True)

    credit = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=6, max_digits=15)
    key = models.TextField(null=True)
    secret = models.TextField(null=True)
```

I have an error when I want to insert a new userProfile as below:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'.

then print the vars(userprofileObject) and realized that `'id': ((), {})`, however, I have not set it. When I removed the `__init__` functions or set id to `None` in insertion code, problem solved.

Any idea?

I need those `__init__` and also don't want to set `id=None` in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how django's models work. You shouldn't change their `__init__` method.
This is why

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the `__init__` method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being saved. Rather than overriding `__init__`, try using one of these approaches:

```
# Add a classmethod on the model class:

from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, title):
        book = cls(title=title)
        # do something with the book
        return book

book = Book.create("Pride and Prejudice")
```

Source https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model

Also read this [Writing a __init__ function to be used in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model#843740)

Comment: so I can not have overloaded __init__ for models

Comment: In theory you can, but you shouldn't. Just use another class constructor like in the example above.