# Django override model subclass create method

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for right ways to override the `create()` method of a subclass.

Basically I'm doing this:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    field1_base = models.IntegerField()
    def __init__(self, field1_base):
        # LOGICS
        self.field1_base = field1_base

class A(Base):
    field2_sub = models.IntegerField()
    def __init__(self, field2_sub, field1_base):
        # LOGICS
        self.field2_sub = field2_sub
        super(A, self).__init__(field1_base)

A(field2_sub=1, field1_base=2)
```

However we can't override the `__init__()` method of a model.

I just want to leave some fields to be assigned in base class's methods.

Is there a proper way to do this using `create()` method?

Of course I can custom `create` method of Base class, however what I want is to invoke Base.create and A.create at the same time on the creation of A, which makes the situation different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580)

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483184/django-model-id-turns-into-a-tuple/39483272#39483272 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model#843740

Comment: yup you can use a simple classmethod as explained in the answer

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Quite similar I think. However in my case I need to invoke the base model's methods at the same time.

Comment: I don't get it. Why not call `super(A, self).create()` then? Or you want to create Base and A objects at the same time with A.create()?

Comment: SardorbekImomaliev thank you for your answer. I want to split the logic into two parts, Base.create() and A.create(). How can I call both on the creation of instance of class A?

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    field1_base = models.IntegerField()

    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.field1_base = kwargs['field1_base']

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # LOGICS
        self = cls()
        self.initialize(*args, **kwargs)
        return self

class A(Base):
    field2_sub = models.IntegerField()

    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).initialize(*args, **kwargs)
        self.field2_sub = kwargs['field1_base']

A.create(field2_sub=1, field1_base=2)
```

Comment: It is a right answer, and actually I'm using the same work around. However I'm still looking for an elegant way of doing so. Thank you all the same.