# Django using an object in an ORM query, within its __init__ function

Tags: python, django

I have a model which exists *only* to combine a number of other models. There are a series of 'payable' objects, with need to be clubbed together into a 'payment' object, called 'ClubbedPayment'.

The model is given a list of payable objects, and it uses them to calculate various attributes. This works fine, so far. These payable objects have a foreign key to ClubbedPayment. Rather than going through the payable objects and adding the new ClubbedPayment object to each of them as a foreign key, it seems easier to add them to ClubbedPayment.payable_set(). I've tried to do this, but it fails because in the `__init__` function, the ClubbedPayment object is not yet saved:

```
class ClubbedPayment(models.Model):
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    paid_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_unpaid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    payment_id = models.UUIDField(null=True, editable=False)
    response = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=140)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=PAYMENT_TYPES)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        objects = kwargs["objects"]
        recipients = set([x.recipient for x in objects])
        types = set([type(x) for x in objects])
        if len(recipients) > 1:
            raise Exception("Cannot club payments to more than one recipient")

        self.total = sum([x.total for x in objects])
        self.recipient = list(recipients)[0]

        for x in objects:
            self.payable_set.add(x)
```

Now, **I know** that overriding `__init__` with non optional arguments is considered dodgy, because it will prevent saving elsewhere, but it's not a problem, because there is only one place in the entire codebase where these objects are created or modified.

The question is, how do I get around this? Calling save() from within the `__init__` function seems like a bad plan ;)

Comment: Noo... `Form`s also construct model objects by calling the constructor, etc. You should really try to avoid overriding the `__init__` (at nearly all cost). Some Django code makes the assumption that it can call the constructor with no arguments. Therefore it is likely a bad idea to use this anyway. It might be better to "move" this to the `.save()` function itself, or something similar.

Comment: Even though there are never any forms regarding this model? It is only ever created in one place, always programmatically

Comment: there still is: in order to *retrieve* the objects from a database, Django will again make use of the constructor, see [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8d2dcc47cd7f6069a1fa2c5b67a329cec5846b7e/django/db/models/base.py#L508).

Comment: I think [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/843580/67579) are probably better.

Comment: Or the approaches as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects). The documentation explicitly states: "*You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the `__init__` method. If you do so, however, **take care not to change the calling signature** as any change may prevent the model instance from being saved.*".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So just stick pretty much the same stuff into a class method?