# Overwrite Django model __init__ method

Tags: python, django, class, model, init

The Ingredient model of my Django project has an `IntegerField` which declares if this ingredient stock is managed by weight, units, or litters.

Although the database has its `integer` value I have to display its name. And instead of looping over every ingredient and setting its value, I thought it was better to overwrite the `__init__` method of the Python class, but I don't get how.

models.py:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ingredient, self).__init__()
        if self.cost_by == 1:
            self.cost_by = 'Units'
        elif self.cost_by == 2:
            self.cost_by = 'Kilograms'
        elif self.cost_by == 3:
            self.cost_by = 'Litters'
#...etc...
```

So far I tried with this, but I'm getting the following error:

```
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 0 were given
```

What argument should I provide?

Comment: how do you call your Ingredient?

Comment: `Ingredient.objects.filter(account=account, brand=brand, name=name)`

Comment: maybe you can try

def __str__(self):
        if self.cost_by == 1:
            self.cost_by = 'Units'
        elif self.cost_by == 2:
            self.cost_by = 'Kilograms'
        elif self.cost_by == 3:
            self.cost_by = 'Litters'
   return self.cost

Comment: I think that @iamcoder was referring to creation time. How are you doing to create Ingredients? By the way, what about declaring as a method ?

Comment: Yup possible a method then when iterating the get ingredients you can manipulate the integer field

Comment: More elaborate discussion of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model

Answer (score 1):

If you define `choices` on a field that contains the value to name mapping then you will get a select field rendered in any `ModelForm` for that field and you will get a method generated on the model to get the display name for the selected value [`get_<field_name>_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):

    COST_BY_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Units'),
        (2, 'Kilograms'),
        (3, 'Litters'),
    )

    cost_by = models.IntegerField(choices=COST_BY_CHOICES)
```

Used like this

```
ingredient = Ingredient(cost_by=1)
print(ingredient.get_cost_by_display())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
     cost_by = .....
     def __str__(self): 
         if self.cost_by == 1: 
             self.cost_by = 'Units' 
         elif self.cost_by == 2: 
             self.cost_by = 'Kilograms' 
         elif self.cost_by == 3: 
             self.cost_by = 'Litters' 
         return self.cost
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I find here is that you did not pass `*args` and `**kwargs` to the Models's `__init__()` and to the super's `__init__()`

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Ingredient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # etc
```