# How is it possible to pass class attributes as arguments of my model class in django

Tags: django

How is it possible to pass class attributes as arguments of my model class? Maybe I am missing something For example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I can get an instance of the above just by doing for example

```
user=User.objects.filter(username='me')[0]
Post(title='random title', content='dqwdf', author=user)
```

which I find strange since the fields of the class are class attributes and not instance attributes.

For example from Python:

```
class Whatever:
   pay = 3
   profit = 2
```

I know I cannot do

```
Whatever(pay=3,profit=2)
```

On topic another question:
Does models.Model have its own **init** ?
If yes since my Post class inherits from it then it should have same **init**.
Is it correct for me to assume that it takes no arguments other than self?

Answer (score 1):

You correctly noted that your class `Post` extended djangos `models.Model`.

You can look at that class [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/28d998a41c92bdac8eeae6509ecc87ed044b30d0/django/db/models/base.py#L404) in djangos github. But thats a lot of code and rather complicated.

Your comparison with a "normal" python class is correct and you could not call `Whatever(pay=3,profit=2)`.

In the second part you first make the right assumption that yes: Your `Post` class inherits models.Model `__init__` method. But init does not **only** take self as argument, but instead it takes exactly that arguments those you specified as class attributes.
That is why `Post(title='random title', content='dqwdf', author=user)` works. It calls the `__init__` method of Post, which is the **init** method of models.Model.

You could of course overwrite the `__init__` method on your own class. You must however call the `super.__init__()` method. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63160853/12497886) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Django's `Model` class does have a custom `__init__` method, which takes any keyword arguments and sets them as fields. This is a relatively common pattern in Python. Functions can get a dictionary of keyword arguments and pass them on to the next function or deal with them in-place.

As part of the keyword arguments, you can pass whatever you'd like as long as it makes sense. So if your model has a field called `pay`, Django's `__init__` method of class `Model` takes this passed parameter and assigns its value to the field.

About your 2nd example, with the regular Python class, the following is a perfectly normal piece of Python code:

```
class Whatever:
    def __init__(self, pay=None, profit=None):
        self.pay = pay
        self.profit = profit

Whatever(pay=3, profit=2)
```

You can also look at Django's `Model` class code, specifically its initialization function here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py

The code is rather complicated but will give you a general idea of how things work. The important thing is that you see that the `__init__` method does *not* only take `self`, but also `**kwargs` which can really be anything.

Comment: Regarding the first part I understand got it. But on the 2nd one I am aware you can structure the Whatever class like you did, but this is not what I wanted. pay and profit I want them to be class variables and not instance ones like you did. How would the code work by doing

class Whatever:

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pay = pay
        self.profit = profit

Whatever(pay=3, profit=2)

Comment: I see. Then django fields aren't a good example, because they are per instance. Also, class variables shouldn't be set through `__init__`, as it is used for instance creation.

Answer (score 0):

ok first you should here use get not filter

```
user=User.objects.get(username='me')
```

- then about your question, you shouldn't worry about the way you initialize the arguments because Django handle all these things for you
- and `models.Model` has its own init method of course and you can override it and make some magic