# Why is the error showing 5 positional arguments while registering the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a chat application on Django. I have created a model to input into a database of the format room_no, user, message. Additionally, I have included the **init** function to extract the data from the database in the form of a string so I can display it on the HTML page. Apart from my method, is there another way to do this? If not, could you please explain my error?

Models:

```
 class chatbox(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,default='Anonymous')
        room = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
        message = models.CharField(max_length=500000,blank=True)
        def __init__(self,name,message):
            self.name = name 
            self.message = message
```

ADMIN

```
admin.site.register(models.chatbox)
```

Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/DjangoChat/chatbox/
chatbox.__init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: `admin.site.register()` requires an `AdminModel` as argument, not a `Model`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a \_\_init\_\_ function to be used in django model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model)