# Resolving a ForeignKey field pointing to the model it belongs to

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model class in Django which has a ForeignKey referencing the model it actually belongs to:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Name")
    #... some other fields
    bar = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to add a custom method in that class which resolves, on the fly, the `name` in a new field, e.g. `bar_resolved` when instantiating it in a QuerySet in a view:

```
from .models import Foo

foo = Foo.objects.all()
# do stuff
```

I've tried this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Name")
    #... some other fields
    bar = models.ForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    # preparing the resolved bar field which should contain the 'name' value corresponding to the id:
    bar_resolved = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name="Bar name resolved",
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def resolve(self):
        if self.bar:
            self.bar_resolved = self.bar.name
        return super(Foo, self).resolve()
```

Then in my view:

```
from .models import Foo

foo = Foo.objects.all()
foo.resolve()
```

but it raises: `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'resolve'`

How could I achieve that? and do I need to hard code a 'resolved' field in my model for that (I think it's overkill to do so)?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why would you have a Foreing key referencing self in the database.

Instead of using resolve, you could probably do it on the save long before - i.e. when setting value of "bar"

Another idea that comes to mind is setting it in the __ init__
method of the model [link to Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843580/writing-a-init-function-to-be-used-in-django-model)

hope this helps.

```
def save(self, force_insert: bool = False, force_update: bool = False) -> None:
    if self.field is None:
        self.field = "value"
    # and so on...
    return super().save(force_insert, force_update)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to [**`annotate`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) your queryset using [**`F expressions`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) with `bar`'s name field:

```
from django.db.models import F

foos = Foo.objects.annotate(bar_resolved=F("bar__name")).all()
for foo in foos:
    print(foo.bar_resolved)
```

Comment: This works the other way: it will grab the value of the rows having the fk equal to the current row pk. Hence, if row pk=1 is referenced by 5 other rows, it will print 4 extra rows having their resolved fields equal to the names of the 4 fields referencing the row 1.